# observable catchError after request failure (axios/redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, axios, redux-observable

**INTRO :**

I have an app in reactjs, using redux, redux-observable and axios-observable.

I face an issue with HTTP error handling.

Let's take the following Epic :

```
const loginRequest = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(UsersActions.loginRequest),
    switchMap((action: {payload:{email: string, password: string}}) => 
        HttpService.PostAsync<any>('token-auth', action.payload).pipe(
            map(response => {
                  // blabla
            }),
            catchError((error: string) => {
                // blabla
            })
        )
    )
);
```

the HttpService looks like this

```
public static PostAsync<T>(targetApi: string, data: any, basePath?: string): AxiosObservable<T> {
    return Axios.post(this.getBaseUrl(targetApi, basePath), data);
}
```

So this works correctly, if the post request fail, I get into the `catchError`, if it doesn't i go into the normal `map`.

**PROBLEM :**

I would like to intercept the response, in order to add a global app error handling, I setup the following function :

```
Axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    console.log(`[response] --> ${response.status}`)
    return response;
}, error => {
    console.log(`[error] --> ${error}`)
    return throwError(error);
})
```

I can now see the log, error, or response depending on the HTTP request result. BUT, I will ALWAYS go into the `map`, and never into the `catchError` of my Epic.

**QUESTION :**

How can I interpect the error, but still throw an error to the redux-observable epic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throwError` only works within RX chain, try use native JS throw

```
Axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    console.log(`[response] --> ${response.status}`)
    return response;
}, error => {
    console.log(`[error] --> ${error}`)
    throw error
})
```